# Trying to add a timer to when mouse movement is detected

Tags: java, eclipse, timer

I am trying to add some code that will start a timer when the mouse is moved a certain number of times, the code below is for the mouse movement. I want the timer to last 10 seconds and alert the user that the timer has started and finished.

```
public class MouseMotionEvent extends JPanel
    implements MouseMotionListener {
BlankArea blankArea;
JTextArea textArea;
static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);


    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseMotionEventDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JComponent newContentPane = new MouseMotionEvent();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); 
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public MouseMotionEvent() {
    super(new GridLayout(0,1));
    blankArea = new BlankArea(Color.YELLOW);
    add(blankArea);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));

    add(scrollPane);

    blankArea.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
}

void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
    textArea.append(eventDescription
            + " (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")"
            + " detected on "
            + e.getComponent().getClass().getName()
            + NEWLINE);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    eventOutput("Mouse moved", e);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    eventOutput("Mouse dragged", e);
}
```

}

Comment: Small side note:  JTextAreas always use `\n` as a line separator, not the system’s line separator.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'am missing something here, but what you ask for seems like a fairly straight forward task. I'am guessing your problem is with setting the "timer" itself?
The java.util.Timer class can be used for this purpose.

So, for your case, a function like

```
private void startTimer()
{
    isTimerRunning = true;
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            isTimerRunning = false;
        }
    }, 10000);

}
```

You will have to call this function from within mouseMoved function like this,

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    eventOutput("Mouse moved", e);
    if (!isTimerRunning)
    {
        startTimer();
    }
}
```

And you could put your alert code along with the code that sets and resets isTimerRunning.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by VGR, javax.swing.Timer is better for using along with other swing components, especially when doing something GUI related. 
From the docs,

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Your code, modified to use, javax.swing.Timer,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MouseMotionEvent extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener
{
BlankArea blankArea;
JTextArea textArea;
private Timer timer;
boolean isTimerRunning = false;
static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex)
    {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI()
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseMotionEventDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent newContentPane = new MouseMotionEvent();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public MouseMotionEvent()
{
    super(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    blankArea = new BlankArea(Color.YELLOW);
    add(blankArea);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));

    add(scrollPane);

    blankArea.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            timer.stop();
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(0, action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(10000);
}

void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e)
{
    textArea.append(eventDescription + " (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")" + " detected on " + e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + NEWLINE);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    eventOutput("Mouse moved", e);
    if (!timer.isRunning())
    {
        timer.start();
    }
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    eventOutput("Mouse dragged", e);
}
}
```

Comment: In Swing applications, javax.swing.Timer is almost always a better choice than java.util.Timer.

Comment: @VGR that actually depends on the use case...if the timer does something GUI related, yes the javax.swing.Timer would be better, but for background tasks, it really doesn't matter...I'll update the answer to include the information...thanks!